# Insert product data although we don't know it belongs to which category using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design, entity-framework-5

I'm developing a eShopping website. I decide that the number of categories (types) of product is limited. As following image:

[image]

I have 3 categories: mobile, tablet, memcard. All of them has common attributes in table Product. Mobile, tablet, memcard table store specific attributes. My problem is how to insert, update, ... with soft-code. At present, I must check if it belongs to which category to do that. Is there smarter method???

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you have these 1:1 associations and no inheritance?

Comment: I don't use inheritance. I don't know what's you mean about 1:1 associations? Could you explain more?

Comment: You have three product types, so why no inheritance: Product as base type and three subtypes.